# Single page application ajax error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on single page application that loads content with ajax calls. My general question is how to catch and handle when those calls fail and what to do next. Obviously, when that happens the users is looking a page framework with nothing to click or do. The code looks like this:

```
$("#page_div").load("ContentStore.html #contentNeeded", bindButtons);
```

Additionally, after some of the page content is loaded, a second call is made to a database to load a table or list. That (adapted and borrowed) code looks like so:

```
var getCustomerList = $.ajax({

  url: "db/db_customerlist.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType : "text",
})

.success(function() {
  var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
  ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = getCustomerList.responseText;
})

.done(function() {
  var selectedCustomer = document.getElementById('btn_customer2_configure');
  selectedCustomer.innerHTML = "Selected";
}) // End .done code

.fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
  alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
  console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
  console.log( "Status: " + status );
  console.dir( xhr );
});// End .fail code

// Code to run regardless of success or failure;
//.always(function( xhr, status ) {
//  alert( "The request is complete!" );
//}); // End .always code
```

Testing, the code works and only fails occasionally but as you can, I don't know why and how to catch / reload / retry.

I'm a rookie, clearly. Any help is appreciated. Go easy on me.

Comment: It seems like you know how to get the `errorThrown`... That error will determine what to investigate.